# Extracting Table in Selenium C# Headless Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am  doing automation of a site and I did all of it. At finally I am storing the table in List and it is working fine without headless Chrome. But when I changed my Chrome browser to "HEADLESS" I am getting empty "td" of table some of them showing and some of them is missing

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.AddArgument("--headless");
IWebElement myTable = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"trades-view active\"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]"));
```

I am attaching both the Screen shots. In first screen shot  Location `{ X=666 , Y=1112 }` and Locationonscreenoncescrolledintview `{ X=659 , Y= 512 }`  This is the case when I am getting the whole table without any problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4oiB.png)

But when I want to change the browser in Headless state then I am getting  Location `{ X=0 , Y=0 }` and Locationonscreenoncescrolledintview `{ X=0 , Y= 0 }`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCTvq.png)

I shall be very thankful to you if you suggest me any changes to do it correctly.

Thanks

Comment: i think in headless mode there are some functionality unavailable. everything with positioning and measuring , screenshooting. so all what needs a screen i guess.

Comment: So , what should i do then? Because I just do not want to show the browser after Pressing "Run " Button. Is there any way to hide the browser other than "headless" method?

Comment: I can verify that headless Chrome should run exactly as a normal visible browser - I have written a library that take screenshots from it. Have you tried resizing the browser?

Comment: No i did not try to resizing the browser.

Comment: If you're running headless, you'll need to try find another solution that doesn't require the XY coordinates of the table. What are you trying to do with those coordinates? Scroll to the table? Wait for it to load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may need to set the window size before navigate to the web.

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.AddArgument("--headless");
option.AddArgument("--window-size=2160,3840");
IWebElement myTable = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"trades-view active\"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]"));
```

Web application may display only some default content and show the remaining when users scroll to the position.

Comment: @user8660794 can you tell me if this answer solve your problem or not?

Comment: @user8660794 That's great. Could you click accept this answer?